# Create std::weak_ptr to an indexed value of an array-type std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, std, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I have a large dataset which essentially loads like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<count; i++){
   auto ptr = std::make_shared<Object>(Object());
   //do stuff with ptr
}
```

This isn't great for performance, due to the memory allocation being piecemeal.
What I want to do is this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object[]> allObjects; //this is stored elsewhere until the program ends

allObjects.reset(new Object[count]);
for(int i=0;i<count; i++){
   auto ptr = std::weak_ptr<Object>(&allObjects[i]);
   //do stuff with ptr
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't compile. I can try it out like this:

```
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<Object>(&allObjects[i]);
```

This works great while the program runs, but of course when all the copies of ptr get destroyed, there's hell to pay. So I would like ptr to be a std::weak_ptr. The main array std::shared_ptr will be stored until after all the weak_ptr are destroyed. So can I create a std::weak_ptr to an indexed member of an array-type std::shared_ptr? Am I just missing some syntax? Do I need a different container type? Or am I missing something fundamentally wrong with the approach?

Comment: Do you actually want a weak_ptr or are you just assuming that you need one in order to not cause a double-free? `shared_ptr` itself already supports the use case you seem to be after without any need for `weak_ptr`.

Comment: Btw. `std::make_shared<Object>(Object())` can be simplified to `std::make_shared<Object>()` which will also avoid a move construction.

Comment: Your example shows you creating some objects as shared_ptr in a loop. but there is nothing on the actual required lifetime, what they are used for, or why you are using dynamically allocated objects to begin with. Cause from all we can see you should just use a normal stack-object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the aliasing constructor of `std::shared_ptr` for this:

```cpp
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<Object>(allObjects, &allObjects[i]);
// and if you wanted a weak_ptr
auto ptr = std::weak_ptr(std::shared_ptr<Object>(allObjects, &allObjects[i]));
```

This `ptr` will use the same control block as `allObjects` (so it will have the same `use_count` and be destroyed at the same time, and crucially only once)